# C++ Trouble opening a file for output

Tags: c++

So I am working on a program for class in which we have to open two different text files to retrieve the appropriate text to be displayed in the console. My code is not opening the file and keeps outputting the else statement ".txt file cannot be open". I've tried several different ways to open the file but with no luck. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  PunchLine program
//  Page 896 Problem 3
//
//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //File stream objects
    fstream inFile;
    string line;

    //Open joke file to read lines to console
    inFile.open("joke.txt", ios::in);

    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        //Read lines from file to console
        while (getline(inFile, line))
        {
            cout << line << endl;
            inFile.close();
        }
    }    
    else 
        cout << "joke.txt file cannot be open.\n";

    //Open punchline file to read last line joke to console
    inFile.open("punchline.txt", ios::in);

    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        //Read last line from file to console
        inFile.seekp(-52L, ios::end);
        getline(inFile, line);
    }    
    else 
        cout << "punchline.txt file cannot be open.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check whether your file exists or is read_only?

Comment: make sure the file is in the same directory as the binary?  please post the output from running 'ls -la'

Comment: The files do exist and I have permission to read and write to the files.

Comment: As Tom said, either use the full path `<drive>:\folder\..` or put it in the same folder as the binary.  Make sure it's not open in any other editors or open it with sharing allowed.  Also make sure there's something in it, if you've been messing around with file handling using this file you might have accidentlly "created" it and overwritten the original!

Comment: @TomSwifty: The directory of the binary has _nothing_ to do with it. The current working directory from which the the program is being executed is important.

Comment: I have tried moving the files around to different directories and still no luck... The files have text in them and I closed them out completely before running my program... I even tried making new .txt files and using those but they will not open either...

Comment: I did the full path and it now works but how will my professor be able to run the program when he won't have access to the full path since the files are on my laptop?

Comment: @Mageneto - Can you try changing the mode? i.e. from in to app. inFile.open("joke.txt", ios::app); I think this might work

Comment: @Mageneto - Also, flush the stream and close the fstream once you are done. Probably this might work with in mode as well i.e. inFile.flush(); inFile.close();

Comment: @Mageneto Since you have proved your program **can** work, you should be able to find out where your program is looking for files to open.  Is this a Visual Studio problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your file exist. If it does, check whether you have the correct path when you open it (check if your .txt files are in the same directory as your .exe file, or specify the full path in your code). If yes, check if the files are read-only.

Comment: This space is for answers, not for questions. If you want more clarity, use the comment section.

Comment: The files do exist and are in the appropriate folder with the correct path. The file has read and write permissions.

Comment: @Mageneto - Do you have an .exe with the name of your program along your joke.txt and punchline.txt files? If not, move your txt files where your exe file is, or specify the full path of your txt files in your code.

Comment: @Mageneto if this was the correct answer, can you elaborate on what the fix was?

Answer (score 2):

When declaring an input file use 
            ifstream inFile;
Also make sure the input file is in the same folder as your .exe

Edit: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ also, this link should help with working with files.

Edit 2: I already posted this in a comment, but I'll just add it to the official answer: "Change your while loop as well. Instead of the if test, use while(inFile.is_open()) and then use your getline statement inside the loop. Because right now your code reads like while get this line from the file is true cout line. So it might not even be doing the while loop."

Comment: I used that link to try and fix my code to get the file to open properly but still no luck; not sure where I'm going wrong here

Comment: Change your while loop as well. Instead of the if test, use while(inFile.is_open()) and then use your getline statement inside the loop. Because right now your code reads like while get this line from the file is true cout line. So it might not even be doing the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should close the file inside the while loop. Otherwise, your file gets closed after only the first line is read in. Move the close statement outside the loop. Same for the second block.

```
if (inFile.is_open())
{
    //Read lines from file to console
    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        cout << line << endl;        
    }
    inFile.close();
}    
else 
    cout << "joke.txt file cannot be open.\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that to ensure that files remain open when needed but for some reason I still get get any input from the files

Comment: Possibly not, but he can't even REACH the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if(!infile)
{
cout<<"cannot open file";
}
```

Comment: `!infile` doesn't *exclusively* check if the file is open it not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to flush the screen. Once you have flushed and closed the stream. The next time you run an application it should open the file.

```
e.g.
inFile.flush();
inFile.close();
```